# How do you determine if you're using Wi-Fi or LTE?

Tags: wi-fi

On Android, how do you tell if you're connected through Wi-Fi or some other type of connection like LTE or 3G?

If I'm sitting at a Starbucks and I sign-in to their Wi-Fi, my phone has both the Wi-Fi and LTE icons showing. How do I know which connection I'm using?

When I'm at a place that has Wi-Fi, I want to use Wi-Fi and not my data from my data plan. Is there a place in Android that specifically tells you?

Comment: Good question! I'm fairly certain that if you're connected to Wifi, then all data (except MMS messaging) is pushed through your Wifi connection. However, I can't really back that up.

Comment: I cannot tell for 4G (not having it), but when I'm on WiFi the WiFi icon shows up, and the cell bars lose their G/E/3G/H symbol. Moreover, the traffic arrows appear on the WiFi icon when transfering data (and *not* on the mobile one); on 4.4+ you unfortunately have to check that in quick-settings, as they removed the arrows from the notification bar.

Comment: Look at the traffic arrows on the top: they move from the 4G to the WIFI symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific place that it shows, but the WiFi connection will take priority over the cellular data. If you wanted, you could perform a SpeedTest to check your service provider, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Also, if you're worried about updates and whatnot using your cellular, the downloads will initiate on WiFi (if you have that option) but they will continue on cellular if you lose the signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go to the Wi-Fi settings menu where you connect to wireless networks and see if you are connected. You should see below the SSID the word "Connected" if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected with WiFi, your mobile connection is automatically disabled.

Comment: Not necessarily, newer (4.3 I think) versions of Android have the option to use both if the connection is unstable, or to swap over. Older devices sometimes used both and I got caught out with that myself a couple of years ago. Generally, you are correct, but most phones are running a customised version of Android and the OEM will sometimes change that setting. Cost me 30 Euro.

Answer (score 0):

An Android app from play store called **Opera Max**

[image: **Opera Max**]

monitors your mobile data and Wi-Fi usage & also **LETS YOU KNOW WHETHER YOU ARE USING DATA OR WI-FI CURRENTLY** in a *persistent notification*

[image: persistent notification]

with using settings in opera max app's settings

Answer (score -2):

In settings, disable mobile data and if you still get Internet then you know. This also guarantees wifi only.
Also if connected to wifi, when you drag down the notification bar, it will show wifi connected.
Or, as op said, go to settings, click wifi and it will show you.